# bulk insert csv from rhel 5 to sql server

Tags: sql-server, linux, csv

I have to import a CSV from a redhat linux server into the SQL Server. I am using the bulk insert command. Below is the query I am using:

```
BULK INSERT dbo.table_name
FROM     '\\servername\folder1\abc.cvs'
    WITH 
    (
        FIELDTERMINATOR = ',' ,
        ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
    )
```

I am getting an error message:

Cannot bulk load because the file "\\servername\folder1\abc.cvs" could not be opened. Operating system error code 53(The network path was not found.).

My guess is I cannot access the linux server from the SQL Server. Is there any way I might be able to import the CSV into the SQL Server.

Thanks

Comment: My guess is that the user running the sqlserver service does not have access to folder1 on the server. Read the security section in the documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx

Comment: I am running the tsql command on the same linux server, so I don't think permissions should be a problem. sqlldr works fine with oracle, but I am unable to load the data into ms sql server. Is there an alternative I could use?

Comment: Where you enter the command doesn't matter. It is executed by the SqlServer process which must run on a windows machine. Check the user for the SqlServer process and verify the access rights on the linux machine for that user. Probably easier to just copy the file to the machine running sqlserver.

Comment: Hi Adrian, I switched to freebcp from bulk insert. I'm getting some errors there as well, but I think it should work. Thanks a lot. :)